# How to model dual-key / secondary index constraint with DynamoDB?

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with HashKey `account_id` and RangeKey `id` for primary key. I have a secondary index HashKey `account_id` and RangeKey `name`. The `name` is optional, but if specified I want the secondary key to be unique (no duplicate names per account). How can I create a DynamoDB schema that retains this constraint on the secondary index?

Comment: as you have said your name field is optional but Range fields cannot be kept null.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you will have to create "reverse" Global Secondary Index. So the `name` becomes the index HashKey and `account_id` is RangeKey. So you can have many accounts with the same `name`, but only one `name` per `account_id`. Basically, one name can have unique accounts only :-) DynamoDB will not let you insert a new row with the same key combination and your constraint will be retained.

Comment: My issue is with the secondary index needing to be unique, not the primary one.  That is, I still have the condition that `account_id` and `id` must be unique.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: In my original answer I omitted the requirement to create new Global Secondary Index. I apologize.